# How to Install cloudstack on RHEL 7.4

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rhel7, apache-cloudstack

I'm trying to install CloudStack managment on RHEL 7.4 Server by following:
http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/4.11/management-server/index.html

**Issue 1:**
/etc/yum.repos.d/cloudstack.repo

The variable $releasever is translated to 7Server which results in url
baseurl=http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/centos/$releasever/4.11/
Is translated to:
http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/centos/7Server/4.11/
Which does not exists. 
I had to modified it to:
http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/centos/7/4.11/
There is also 
http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/rhel/7/4.11/
I don’t know which of the two is required.

**Issue 2:**
When doing:
sudo yum install cloudstack-management

Error: Package: cloudstack-management-4.11.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (cloudstack)
           Requires: apache-commons-daemon-jsvc

I was not able to install this missing package.

**Issue 3:**
sudo yum install mysql-server
results in:
No package mysql-server available.

I understand that RHEL 7.4  comes with MariaDB and not MySql. I don’t have instructions on how to configure the MariaDB for CloudStack.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using redhat, you need to use below repo:
http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/rhel/7/4.11/

To get apache-commons-daemon-jsvc, you need to enable base repo as this package is provided by redhat.

You can install mariaDB, instead of mysql and then follow exact steps from documentation.
Only difference will be while restarting/starting/enabling service use mariadb instead of mysql.